# Which subsystems exist in Linux for general purpose configuration storage?

Tags: linux, configuration, storage

I'm looking for a listing of general purpose configuration storage subsystems on Linux.
I have tried looking for it in the documentation but I got no further then the standard configuration storage subsystems (file-system, environment variables).

As an example on Windows I know of:

- file-system
- environment variables
- windows registry

I'm looking for a similar listing for Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no equivalent of the windows registry.  There's a convention of where to put configuration files, but that's it.  Even environment variables must either be set manually every login or stored in configuration files.

Comment: The filesystem really encompasses a lot of stuff... pretty much everything actually, since the environment variables have to come from somewhere too. If you mean configuration of the system and system application, it's mostly files under `/etc`, with a number of different file formats. For user applications, usually dotfiles in the home directory. But I don't think there's much of a centralized system, other than those piles of files. Though systemd has its own structured directories, and maybe the desktop environments have some for that stuff. So, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @ilkkachu Well there are several ways an application can obtain its configuration. Either from files, from environment variables and, in windows, from the windows registry. What I'm looking for is types of storage in Linux other than those, if there are any. I don't know Linux that well, so I'm wondering whether there are any other types storage where an application can obtain its configuration.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Ow really? I was unaware of that, thank you. So other than those two types of storage (which boil down to files either way), Linux offers no other types configuration storage? I mean it makes sense, but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux plain text files are normally used for storing applications and services configuration.

- `/etc` is used for system services.
- `$HOME/.config/{appname|appname/}` is preferred for applications run by a normal user though old apps and utils may use `$HOME/{.appname|.appname/}`.
- Gnome 2 used a system similar to Windows registry, [GConf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GConf) but it's being deprecated.

Comment: So to the best of your knowledge, other than files, environment-variables and (the in the process of being deprecated) GConf, there are no other types of configuration storage on linux? I that case I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Byebye None that I'm aware of having used Linux for over two decades.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing! I've marked your response as the answer to my question.